# How do I make a ComboBox in Bootstrap Vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, combobox, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to make a ComboBox in Bootstrap Vue v2.21.2, without using Vuetify's `v-combobox`.

I've tried using https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox but it doesn't seem to work well, and I'd rather use an existing Bootstrap component than apply an external CSS plugin.

Is there a way to create a ComboBox in Bootstrap Vue? Or do I have to switch to Vuetify for this?

Comment: Could you please share what you tried? Tell us what goes wrong, and please share some code with us.

Comment: Normally I would, but I'm not trying to fix any code here, I'm trying to find if there is an option or component somebody knows about that I don't.

Comment: Ok, I see now; maybe using https://vue-multiselect.js.org/ will help you since this package provides searching in dropdowns. I looked a little for the `combobox` title and found this `vue-bootstrap-ajax-combobox`. I recommend `vue-multiselect` because I've been using it with `b-vue`. I didn't post it as an answer because I wasn't sure that I understand your problem. .`

Comment: The "Select with Search" was exactly what I needed, thank you so much. I've found a few packages that I'm going to try out by using that term. You should note that Search with Select is equivalent to Combobox, because I never found the things I needed since I didn't know the term for the component I was looking for.

Comment: Your welcome :) If you think that If I post that comment as an answer is helpful for the community, let me know. If not, please answer the question yourself for helping people that have this question.

Comment: Hi @ImanShafiei , you should post your comment as an answer. It's working perfectly. TYSM again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org) will help you since this package provides `searching in dropdowns`.

I looked a little for the combobox title and found this `vue-bootstrap-ajax-combobox`.

I recommend `vue-multiselect` because I've been using it with `bootstrap-vue`.

I prepared one snippet to show how `vue-multiselect` works perfectly for searching in dropdowns.

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: {
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@domain.com'
    },
    options: [{
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@domain.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ada',
        email: 'ada@domain.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'Nick',
        email: 'nick@domain.com'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    custom_label(option) {
      return `${option.name} - ${option.email}`
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.2/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :multiple="true" track-by="email" :custom-label="custom_label">
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
</div>
```